# Display tooltip data outside of tooltip

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I want to show the tooltip data (for eg: x and y values), outside of tooltip in a different component, by finding the tooltip mouseover (trigger) event.

So that tooltip data is shown in a different component (when we do a mouseover over graph), instead on the tooltip itself.

May I know if this is possible? How do I make use of mouseover event to do the same.
I would appreciate a simple demo if feasible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that purpose, you can use the `mouseOver` point's event:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            const value = `x: ${this.x}, y: ${this.y}`;
            document.getElementById('customTooltip').innerText = value;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qrdevyzw/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver

or `formatter` function for tooltip:

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      const value = `x: ${this.x}, y: ${this.y}`;
      document.getElementById('customTooltip').innerText = value;

      return false;
    }
  }
```

---

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q7bjug9w/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter